# "Log In As" with ASP - preventing going back

Tags: security, authentication, asp-classic

I have a feature in an ASP app where a user can "log in as" someone else (teachers logging in as students to check interfaces, etc). The problem is when they hit the back button and try to access things as instructors again.

What's the best way to prevent this? Is there a way of preventing them from going back into those pages? I do checks on individual pages for authorization, but I wonder if there isn't something more elegant.

Comment: asp.net? asp-classic? I'm tagging it asp-classic until you fix it for one or the other, since we're trying to clean up/disambiguate the asp tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expire the cache, the following needs to be put on every page that requires authentication:

```
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-store"
Response.CacheControl = "no-store"
Response.Expires = -1
```